# User limit in Microsoft demo tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

How many Azure AD users can be added in Microsoft Demo Tenant?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50,000 objects, if you're only adding users (no groups or any other types) then 50,000

Comment: You could try logging a support query, if you have a valid reason to be testing with so many objects they may increase the limit for you.